# Should I keep all migrations since the dawn of time in my Heroku-pushing repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In the past (without Heroku), I've deleted my migration files once I've run them and don't expect to roll back. However, I've noticed that Heroku likes to run every migration every time I run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Is it going to get upset if I remove the files?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the migrations?

Comment: you should read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: technically, you don't really need the migrations when you deploy to heroku.  you can just always push you current db to heroku to update the database structure.  But this shouldn't be the solution.  You should always commit every migration you run.

Comment: how would you push the database structure? isn't this exactly what migrations are for? You don't need migrations once they have been run as if you ever need to re-load the database, you should load the schema anyway